# How to use the canonical tag in multi language websites that is SEO friendly?

Tags: seo

I have doubts about using the *canonical* tag in multilingual websites.
This is how I currently use the canonical tag on a multilingual website:
English Website:

```html
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-se" href="https://EnglishDomain.se/url.html"/>
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="se-se" href="https://SwedishDomain.se/url.html"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://EnglishDomain.se/url.html" />
```

Also in Swedish Website I use this lines:

```html
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-se" href="https://EnglishDomain.se/url.html"/>
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="se-se" href="https://SwedishDomain.se/url.html"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://SwedishDomain.se/url.html" />
```

My Question:
Am I using it correctly or is it wrong to use the canonical tag on both websites?

I already add Canonical tag to both websites, I am not sure it is correct. I mean, I just think about that maybe I have to add canonical tag to only one of the websites?

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide which of the two pages is the preferred language for your content (assuming that the content is the same).  Then point both pages to teh same url.

If Swedish was your preferred language then put this in both the English and Swedish pages

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://SwedishDomain.se/url.html">
```

However, Google is no longer recommending using canonicals

> **Specifying language and location**
> We've expanded our support of the `rel="alternate" hreflang` link element to handle content that is translated or provided for multiple geographic regions. The `hreflang` attribute can specify the language, optionally the country, and URLs of equivalent content. By specifying these alternate URLs, our goal is to be able to consolidate signals for these pages, and to serve the appropriate URL to users in search. Alternative URLs can be on the same site or on another domain.

From [New markup for multilingual content](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content)

Example from the same page

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="https://es-es.example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-MX" href="https://es-mx.example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://en.example.com/">
```

Comment: In fact, I summarize the languages. I plan to have 6 domains for 3 countries (each country English and local language), I used canonical since product A is my main product in that category (I have around 9 products in that category) due to that I use canonical for product A.